# Missing commands in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Sorry if this is a dumb question - I'm just getting started with AWS - I've installed the AWS CLI utility on Windows, and configured it with my access key and secret. The command "aws --version" says "aws-cli/2.8.10 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off".  I'm trying to run "aws assume-impersonation-role" as documented here:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workmail/assume-impersonation-role.html
```

but I get the error "invalid choice". The list of valid choices has nothing like what I'm looking for.  Is there some extension or add-on I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to check the obvious, are you doing:

```
aws assume-impersonation-role --organization-id … --impersonation-role-id …
```

rather than the intended

```
aws workmail assume-impersonation-role --organization-id … --impersonation-role-id …
```

?

Comment: Sorry, adding "workmail" as the first parameter was not so obvious to me - that does work.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries... I spent ages doing almost the same thing earlier this week: missing a parameter to `aws` that in hindsight was clear!